# How to count rows and return the data from a ce

Tags: excel, worksheet

I have a spreadsheet with dates listed in Column A, and Business Day or Weekend designation in Column B. In column C, I'd like to key a transit day number (shown entered in C13), and have a formula to count down that number of rows that are labeled "Business Day", and return the date in the cell in column D beside the transit day. (Shown in D13).

Also in the rows to the right, if a transit day is entered, I'd like to count backwards up the sheet and returns the date.

```
CARRIER TRANSIT TIME PERFORMANCE CHECK                                        CHECK FOR SETTING SHIP DATE FROM DELIVERY DATE                        
Ship Date   TYPE           Transit Days     Arrival Date   Delivery Date   TYPE          Transit Days   DATE TO SHIP ON
3/2/2014    Weekend                                        3/2/2014        Weekend                
3/3/2014    Business Day                                   3/3/2014        Business Day                
3/4/2014    Business Day                                   3/4/2014        Business Day                
3/5/2014    Business Day                                   3/5/2014        Business Day                
3/6/2014    Business Day                                   3/6/2014        Business Day                
3/7/2014    Business Day                                   3/7/2014        Business Day                
3/8/2014    Weekend                                        3/8/2014        Weekend                
3/9/2014    Weekend                                        3/9/2014        Weekend                
3/10/2014   Business Day                                   3/10/2014       Business Day                
3/11/2014   Business Day        6           3/19/2014      3/11/2014       Business Day        6        3/3/2014   
3/12/2014   Business Day                                   3/12/2014       Business Day                
3/13/2014   Business Day                                   3/13/2014       Business Day                
3/14/2014   Business Day                                   3/14/2014       Business Day                
3/15/2014   Weekend                                        3/15/2014       Weekend                
3/16/2014   Weekend                                        3/16/2014       Weekend                
3/17/2014   Business Day                                   3/17/2014       Business Day                
3/18/2014   Business Day                                   3/18/2014       Business Day                
3/19/2014   Business Day                                   3/19/2014       Business Day
```

Comment: What is your question, SO does not do you're work for you.

Comment: `WORKDAYS` should be the function that gives you the answer you are after

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users kindly point the issues in your code.
Please edit your post and publish what exactly have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WORKDAY` function would give you the required date without actually using your Business Day/Weekend designation, e.g. in D5 copied down

`=IF(COUNT(C5),WORKDAY(A5,C5),"")`

For counting backwards you can use the same formula but with a negated count, so in H5 copied down

`=IF(COUNT(G5),WORKDAY(E5,-G5),"")`

Comment: Thanks. This formula works great for both ways. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. First time I have used this site and missed that step.